# Laravel always sets the default value

Tags: laravel

I am trying to do registration with user profile picture upload.(I am forced to do it this way)
I created the migration like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->string('prenom');
        $table->string('type')->default('visiteur');
        $table->boolean('confirme')->default(false);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('photo_url')->default('default_photo_profile.jpg');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

the create function :

```
$request = request();


if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $file = $request->file('photo');
            $fullname=$data['nom'].'_'.date("Y-m-d",time()).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('images', $fullname);
        }

        return User::create([
            'nom' => $data['nom'],
            'prenom' => $data['prenom'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'photo_url' => $fullname,
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
  }
```

and the form for the file field is like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="photo_url">Photo profile</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control-file" id="photo_url">
</div>
```

everything is working fine except the photo_url field, it always sets the default value in the migration and not the value I set in the create function.
$fullname is initiated and already declared.

the entire form :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Register') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="nom" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nom</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('nom') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="nom" value="{{ old('nom') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('nom'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('nom') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="prenom" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Prénom</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('prenom') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="prenom" value="{{ old('prenom') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('prenom'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('prenom') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Email</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Mot de pass</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Mot de pass confirmation</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="photo_url">Photo profile</label>
                        <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control-file" id="photo_url">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Envoyer
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: are you trying to upload photo when user is registered or after registration ?

Comment: the file is uploaded

Comment: when user is registered.

Comment: the user is stored in database and file uploaded to storage but the problem is in the field photo_url it always stores the default value in the migration.

Comment: the validation on the photo is 'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'

Comment: Can you show the entire form? Try debugging the value for `$fullname`: `dd($fullname);`.

Comment: okay do this:
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $file = $request->file('photo');
            $fullname=$data['nom'].'_'.date("Y-m-d",time()).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('images', $fullname);
        }
else {
      $fullname = "default_photo_profile.jpg";
}

and remove default from photo_url in the migration

Comment: I tried using a static value and nothing working I will show now the form

Comment: make sure that your form has `method="POST"` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @SalmanZafar I want to know why it's not working since in previous projects it was working fine.

Comment: @Jerodev dd($fullname); -> "el_2018-07-17.jpg"

Comment: @floyd whichh version of laravel you are using for this project?

Comment: latest version 5.6

Comment: Can you post the `User` model?

Comment: Show me your User Model

Comment: may be you don;t have $fillable photo_url in your user model.

Comment: @SalmanZafar correct now it's working, I forgot to put it there. Thank you.

Comment: @floyd pleasure. there is one more way to do this.if you don't want to add photo_url to your fillable array.

Comment: @SalmanZafar I woul like to know more ways to do things, if you can please show me how.

Comment: okay let me post a complete answer then

Comment: ok thank you, take your time.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

so according to your code in your model you have to add the `photo_url in $fillable array` like below.

```
$fillables = ['nom','prenom','type','confirme','email','password','photo_url'];
```

okay now there are 3 ways to do it with $fillable is first way and  you are doing it right now.

2nd way:

```
   if ($request->hasFile('photo')) { 
    $file = $request->file('photo'); 
    $fullname=$data['nom'].'_'.date("Y-m-d",time()).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $path = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('images', $fullname); 
   } 
   else 
   { 
     $fullname = "default_photo_profile.jpg";  
   } 

return User::create([
            'nom' => $data['nom'],
            'prenom' => $data['prenom'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'photo_url' => $fullname,
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
```

and in your migration change this  `$table->string('photo_url')->default('default_photo_profile.jpg');` to `$table->string('photo_url');`

3rd way:

```
$fullname = "default_photo_profile.jpg";

if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $file = $request->file('photo');
            $fullname=$data['nom'].'_'.date("Y-m-d",time()).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('images', $fullname);

 return User::create([
            'nom' => $data['nom'],
            'prenom' => $data['prenom'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'photo_url' => $fullname,
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
        }

        return User::create([
            'nom' => $data['nom'],
            'prenom' => $data['prenom'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'photo_url' => $fullname,
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
  }
```

okay these are the ways to do it. i would prefer first and second way 3rd one is lengthy.

**Note:** for 2nd and 3rd case you have to change your migration from this `$table->string('photo_url')->default('default_photo_profile.jpg');` to `$table->string('photo_url');`
Hope you get it.

Comment: @floyd pleasure.

Comment: FYI, default values on the table should be a counter-measure to lack of input. 3rd way does exactly...nothing because the fillables is empty. All it requires is to contain the variable in the fillables in order to use the Create method. One correct way to go around it is to use INSERT instead of CREATE. GL copypasta

Comment: why to use counter-measure when you can do it by so many ways.
i my self implemented this over a year ago as it is better.
either make your filed nullable or if you want to store data init then use if condition.
why to use to insert when you can do this by eloquent which is super easy.
i don't prefer the 3rd way but still it's possible solution.
it entirely depends of the developer which one he wants to use.
i will prefer second.
here's the link to that implementation https://github.com/salmanzafar949/SocialMediaAppLaravel_5.3/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a value for `$photo_url`, make sure you have 'photo_url' in your `$fillables`.

When you have $fillables, it only inserts (via `User::create`) what has in that array, otherwise it doesn't submit for that variable.

Your `$fillables` should look like this:

```
$fillables = ['nom','prenom','type','confirme','email','password','photo_url'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `'photo'` in `$fillable` array in **User** model:

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'photo_url', 
];
```